# ¿Cómo resto una suma al remover un item con splice? angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Supongamos que he registrado dos productos uno cuesta 100$ y el otro 15$, pero he decidido quitar el producto de 100$. necesito que me ayuden a como actualizar ese subtotal y el neto al remover un producto de esa tabla.

```
        $scope.guardarproductoCompra = function () {
            var NombreProducto = "";
            //$scope.ProductoCompra = "";
            $.each($scope.Productos, function (index, value) {
                if (value.ID_PRODUCTO == $scope.Productos.ID_PRODUCTO) {
                    NombreProducto = value.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO;
                }
            })

            $scope.TablaProductosCompra.push({
                CANTIDAD: $scope.ProductoCompra.CANTIDAD,
                ID_COMPRA: $scope.ProductoCompra.ID_COMPRA,
                VALOR_UNITARIO: $scope.ProductoCompra.VALOR_UNITARIO,
                NOMBRE_PRODUCTO: NombreProducto,
                COD_PRODUCTO: $scope.Productos.ID_PRODUCTO
            })

            $scope.removeItem = function (index) {
                $scope.TablaProductosCompra.splice(index, 1);
            }


            $scope.valor.neto =+ ($scope.ProductoCompra.CANTIDAD * $scope.ProductoCompra.VALOR_UNITARIO) + $scope.valor.neto;

            $scope.valor.iva2 = +($scope.valor.neto * 0.19);

            $scope.valor.total =+ ($scope.valor.neto + ($scope.valor.neto * 0.19));

            console.log($scope.valor.total);
        }
```

Comment: Tu `splice` hace su función, pero quizá deberías plantearte rehacer el cálculo del total como una función llamada cada vez que se modifique `$scope.TablaProductosCompra` desde [`$scope.$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection).

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te comentan, quizás lo mejor sea sacar la suma a una función que te facilite mas la cosa.

```
$scope.calcularPrecio = function (producto){
    $scope.valor.neto = (producto.CANTIDAD * producto.VALOR_UNITARIO) + $scope.valor.neto;
    $scope.valor.iva2 = $scope.valor.neto * 0.19;
    $scope.valor.total = $scope.valor.neto + $scope.valor.iva2;
}

$scope.quitarProducto = function (index){
    var producto = $scope.TablaProductosCompra[index];
    if(producto){
        $scope.TablaProductosCompra.splice(index, 1);
        var precioNetoProducto = (producto.CANTIDAD * producto.VALOR_UNITARIO)
        $scope.valor.neto =  $scope.valor.neto - precioNetoProducto;
        $scope.valor.iva2 = $scope.valor.neto * 0.19;
        $scope.valor.total = $scope.valor.neto + $scope.valor.iva2;
    }    
}
```

En la función de calcularPrecio, envíale el producto y con ese objeto puedas hacer los cálculos.

Luego, en la función de quitarProducto, puedes seguir mandando el index. Con ese index, obtén el producto de tu TablaProductosCompra y con el podrás calcular los precios que debes de restar.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda